# jQuery Sparkline Boxplots - What does it expect for values array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to wrap my head around the values that jQuery Sparklines expects in the values array for box plots. It doesn't seem to expect raw statistical values, but rather min value, 1st quartile value, median value, 3rd quartile value, and max value as the values array. Is that so? I went through the minified JavaScript and that seems to be the case, but I'm just not making full sense of it so wanted to double check with anyone that's worked with the Sparlines boxplots.

I have the option of showing outliers disabled. I also let the boxplots determine the chart min and max values. The code to construct my boxplot is:

```
$('#ctl00_MainBodyContentPlaceHolder_rptrMultipleChoiceDimensionResult_ctl00_lblBoxPlot')
    .sparkline(
        [3.13, 3.2925, 3.375, 3.3975, 3.53],
        {
            type: 'box',
            targetColor: '#fff',
            boxLineColor: '#777',
            boxFillColor: '#ccc',
            whiskerColor: '#777',
            medianColor: '#000',
            lineColor: '#777',
            width: '500px',
            height: '30px',
            showOutliers: false,
            rangeColors: ['#eee', '#bbb', '#888', '#000']
        }
    );
```

From what I've gathered, when showOutliers is disabled the API expects the values array to be passed as min value, 1st quartile value, median value, 3rd quartile value, and max value. Just wanted to confirm that that is indeed the case, if anyone has used the component before.

The documentation doesn't really describe what it expects for the values either: http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, it does expect a raw array of values - It will compute the IQR, etc from those values to draw the boxplot.

If you wish to calculate those values yourself, then you can set the raw option to true in which case you pass in values of [low_outlier, low_whisker, q1, median, q3, high_whisker, high_outlier] (assuming the showOutliers option is set to true, else omit the first and last values).

I'll update the docs at some point to provide a solid example.

Incidentally you can download the non-minified version of the plugin from the site too if you want to read the code.